# Insert in SQL table using select with column values from another select

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I have an insert statement in MSSQL as follows:

```
INSERT INTO A(KeyId, KeyName, Name)
SELECT ('?','?',BName)FROM B
```

The value of KeyId and KeyName are retreived from another table D

Table B- Table C mapping is BName= XName
Table C- Table D mapping is Xname = XName
There are like 1000 records from B which need to be inserted into A. how can i write an SP for the same?

Table A Columns - KeyId,KeyName,Name
Table B Columns - Id,BName
Table C Columns - XName
Table D Columns - KeyId,KeyName, XName

Comment: what is the mapping between table B and C?

Comment: You write "SELECT KeyId,KeyName FROM C WHERE Name = 'SomeNameFromTableB'", but there's no NAME column in C...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005 and later you can use `outer apply`:

```
insert into A(KeyId, KeyName, Name)
select 
    CALC.KeyId,
    CALC.KeyName,
    B.Name
from B
   outer apply (select KeyId,KeyName from C where C.Name = 'SomeNameFromTableB') as CALC
```

For prior versions you can declare variables, fill it with values and use that variables:

```
declare @KeyId bigint, @KeyName nvarchar(max)
select @KeyId = KeyId, @KeyName = KeyName FROM C WHERE Name = 'SomeNameFromTableB'

insert into A(KeyId, KeyName, Name)
select 
    @KeyId,
    @KeyName,
    B.Name
from B
```

**UPDATE** As from OP's comment:

> > The value of Name='SomeNamefromTableB' is actually the value i am inserting i.e. B.Name

So, in this case you just can use join:

```
insert into A(KeyId, KeyName, Name)
select 
    C.KeyId,
    C.KeyName,
    B.BName
from B
   left outer join C on C.XName = B.BName
```

Comment: Hi The value of Name='SomeNamefromTableB' is actually the value i am inserting i.e. B.Name. Will it work if i replace it?

Comment: 2nd option can have problem if there are more then one rows returned by `select from C`. one more thing : as per question `Name` column is not in table `C` but used in where clause.

Comment: Updated the question. The column in C is XName. It contains some value from BName in table B

Comment: @Eve in this case you just can use join. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev i cannot use a simple join. Its a little more complex than that. I have elaborated the table structure . Updated the question

Comment: @Eve It would be better if you provided all your conditions in question, not adding it one-by-one. Anyway, if there is mapping from B to C and from C to D - I see no reason why don't you just write two joins. Or even one join, because for me condition `Table B- Table C mapping is BName= XName Table C- Table D mapping is Xname = XName` looks like `B - D is B.BName = D.XName`

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
INSERT INTO A(KeyId,KeyName,Name)
SELECT c.KeyId,
       c.KeyName,
       c.XName
FROM   C
       JOIN B
         ON c.XName = b.Name
```

This will insert those rows from C where `c.XName` is present in `b.Name`.